# Synced OneDrive migration question

Tags: migration, onedrive-for-business

I am moving/upgrading an on prem SharePoint farm from 2013 to 2016. Users are using their MySites and have Synced them. The URL to the mySite will be changing. I have a lot of users and I would rather not send out instructions on how to stop the current OneDrive from syncing, cleanup the folder and hen sync to the new site. I would like some way to programmatically change the reference that is in place.

I have checked the registry and have not found the reference. I did also then expand to all settings that I can find, and I cannot find the reference anywhere.

Can anyone please provide me the location the reference is stored, or how you would accomplish this same task?